# Disable M2E Pro

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, m2e, m2epro

We use to use M2E Pro and now we want to disable it
The problem is that now whenever we try accessing an order that was created by M2E pro we get an error:

> The requested Payment Method is not available

Comment: Contact Extension provider or provide some piece of code , otherwise this question not belongs to here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removed payment method, old orders not loading](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29398/removed-payment-method-old-orders-not-loading)

Comment: Another solution is to change the payment methods of existing M2E orders as described here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94243/in-which-table-payment-method-information-of-order-save

Comment: Thanks, the reason I posted this here was because I was hoping that someone else came across the same issue, specifically with M2E Pro

Comment: I ended up creating a payment module with the code m2epropayment